# Should I split large table into smaller identical ones in this case?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

Imagine that you have a multisite script, e.g. having multiple instances if the same thing (like forum hosting). If using MySQL is it better to create a new set of tables for each site or have one large table with a site_id column?

One table is of course easier to maintain, but what abut performance?
Also what if I used Redis, would the answer be any different?

Comment: Will people need access to more than one site data?

Comment: Give more info. It depends on what type of site you will create. How many requests per hour (average) you will have and so on and so on...

Comment: The closest example would be a forum hosting. Tables are completely separate and data is never used from more than 1 table at once.

Answer (score 0):

Stop trying to outsmart your DBMS, you won't win that battle. Your data should be broken into tables logically, not for performance reasons.

What you are describing is effectively a weak attempt at trying to re-invent an index.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to see much difference in any performance from having multiple tables, as John says, Indexes would do that better.

But you may see what appear to be performance boosts because table locks would be specific to that site's forum table instead of locking out the single forum table for all sits. But good queries and architecture are a better way of preventing those locks from impacting performance.

You can have multiple databases on the same DB server, one for each of your sites. This kind of makes sense as it would mean each site would have it's independent user tables as well as forum tables and then would each have their own resource pools. But this duplicate data if a single user is going to be using multiple forums and now has to have multiple user records (as well as any other data not specific to the forum posts).

You can reduce lag by having entirely different DB servers located near (in the network sense) the application server that is using them. But really, now days it take a server across the country less than a tenth of a second to respond to ping, and that's for home users, probably a bit better for servers sitting at a hosting provider.

All of this is moot unless you are actually seeing usage beyond what a single table in a single db can handle. And until you have some real-world statistics as to where bottlenecks are, don't knock yourself out trying to fix things that you don't even know if they will ever break.